# Process will not be killed

Tags: macos, lsof

I have the Jenkins server running on my machine.

I did `lsof -i :8080`, I took the PID and then I ran `sudo kill -9 PID`.

However, when I go to `localhost:8080` Jenkins is still up and `lsof -i :8080` shows a different PID.

I think some other process might be starting Jenkins all the time.

Can I find out the parent process and kill it?

Or is there a better way to get rid of the process?

Comment: A better way, perhaps: `http://localhost:8080/exit`

Comment: Well, I can only POST to this address. And if I post I get `No valid crumb was included in the request`.

Comment: Yes, you need to supply credentials or use the Jenkins CLI: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 shutdown`. See [this documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance).